# Get indexPath in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsindexpath

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell that is shown in a TableView. Each cell has a text field. When the textFieldDidEndEditing func is called, I want to save the entered text as an attribute of an NSManagedObject in my Managed Object Context.

This function is implemented in my tableViewCell class:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    let viewController = ViewController()
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath!
    viewController.updateCommitsInMOC(self, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
}
```

And this is the function it calls. This function is implemented in my ViewController class, the one that controls the TableView which is made up of the tableViewCells:

```
func updateCommitsInMOC(cell: CommitTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Fetch Commit
    let commit = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Commit

    // Update Cell
    commit.contents = cell.commitContents.text!
    if cell.repeatStatus.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 { commit.repeatStatus = true }
    saveManagedObjectContext()
}
```

I'm of course open to any suggestions as to other ways to implement the saving behavior every time the user is done editing the text field.

Comment: do you actually have a problem? why don't you pass the text as a parameter instead of the cell (or as well as)? same goes for the status thing

Comment: @Wain I wouldn't know how to do that. But I think the basic problem still remains: I need to go through every cell in my table view and save the contents of a text field contained within the cell to the managed object context. If you can think of a function that only takes the contents as a variable and know how to implement it so that it is called by each table view cell appropriately, please leave an answer!

Comment: you already have code which does that when a text field is edited, i'm still not sure what your actual problem is. you're just not happy with the solution you have or there's an actual issue that means what you have doesn't work?

Comment: @Wain What I have doesn't work. I can't update the managedObjectContext when the textFieldDidEndEditing func is called because I don't know how to make a connection between the individual cells and the managed objects, between the text fields and the contents attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question "How do I get the IndexPath"?  Instead of the UITableviewCell trying to figure out what it's indexPath is in textFieldDidEndEditing, why don't you just figure it out within updateCommitsInMOC function?

Assuming you have a reference to your tableView you can just do this

```
func updateCommitsInMOC(cell: CommitTableViewCell) {

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
        return
    }

    // Fetch Commit
    let commit = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Commit

    // Update Cell
    commit.contents = cell.commitContents.text!
    if cell.repeatStatus.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 { commit.repeatStatus = true }
    saveManagedObjectContext()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a sweet and short solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tag as row in cell textField.
like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCell")
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

and the textField delegate:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    let viewController = ViewController()
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: textField.tag, section: 0)
    viewController.updateCommitsInMOC(self, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
}
```

or you can use the superview:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    let view = textField.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell

    let viewController = ViewController()
    let indexPath = itemTable.indexPathForCell(cell)
    viewController.updateCommitsInMOC(self, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
}
```

Comment: please don't suggest tags for this, at least not without suggesting a good if not so fast to implement solution too

Comment: Your second solution seems to be the better option. That's what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use in your tableview the 
`setEditing(editing, animated: animated)` method.
Then inside of it you can manage the single object retrieving it from the `fetchResultController.indexPathForObject(inputObject)` or as you used `fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)`. 
Finally you can use `self.managedObjectContext.saveToPersistentStore()` or `self.managedObjectContext.save()`.